# Laravel 10 ManyToMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, eloquent-relationship, laravel-10

So, in my App an User can have multiple companies for which he can have records.

I have stated the following methods

**User.php**

```
public function companies() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'companies_users', 'company_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

**Company.php**

```
public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'companies_users', 'company_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

In **CompanyController** i'm attaching the user id on create using the following

```
public function store(StoreCompanyRequest $request) {
        $company = \App\Models\Company::create($request->all());
        $company->users()->attach(Auth::user()->id);
        return redirect()->route('companies.index')->with('success','Company has been created successfully.');
    }
```

Pivot table **companies_users** is updated just fine

[image]

However when I list or dd the results i only get 1 company.

[image]

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `companies` relation on the `User` model is incorrect. You should swap the position of `user_id` and `company_id` and it should work.

```php
public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'companies_users', 'user_id', 'company_id');
}
```

As a generic rule, for `belongsToMany` relationships, the third parameter would have the name of the model you are defining on. For example, if you are defining the relation of the `User` model, the third parameter would be `user_id`

**Tip**

Since your models follow Laravel naming standards, you could also just skip the 3rd and 4th parameters and Laravel will guess it on its own.

```php
public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'companies_users');
}
```